# If then Formula Assistance

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet I am using for payments. I have certain rows that needs to match a particular column of numbers to say $0.00 for the value. Basicly, I need certain numbers to be zeroed out as they are exempt from payment and this is something I do monthly so it changes depending on what is listed for the number in Column A and the zeroed out numbers are on the second sheet. I was thinking a vlookup, then using maybe a if then as well. I can't think of what would be the best combination.

If Column A matches Sheet Column A then Column , E, F, G, H will auto fill with $0.00 and column D will have a 0 in it.

Is this something possible?

Comment: I don't do a lot with Excel functions but this would be pretty simple to do using a custom macro.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it should be possible, try and amend the below for your problem and let us know if you run into any issues. Essentially it compares the A cell in the row to the A cell in the other sheet, if they match it will be a 0, if they don't you can put something else where it says "Something else".

```
=IF($A1='Sheet 2'!$A1,0,"Something Else")
```